# How can I get text inputs to align without using an HTML table?

Tags: html, css

I need to have a set (several "rows") of label/text input elements. I want the text input elements to vertically align without using an HTML table.  It would seem setting all the labels to a great enough width should do this, but this does not work:

HTML

```
<label>Invoice #</label>
<input type="text" id="invoiceNumber"></input>
</br>
<label>Date</label>
<input type="text" id="date"></input>
```

CSS

```
label {
    font-family: Consolas, 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
    margin-left: 10px;
    min-width: 120px;
}
```

jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/8wRT3/1/

Comment: You mean, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EycNZ/)?

Comment: As @insertusernamehere demonstrates, the real problem is that <label> tags are inline by default, which means a "width" has no effect. That's all that needs to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, on your jsFiddle, "//" isn't correct procedure for commenting out CSS code. What you should do is this:

HTML

```
<label>Invoice #</label>
<input type="text" id="invoiceNumber"></input>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<label>Date</label>
<input type="text" id="date"></input>
```

CSS: Change the input to this:

```
input {
    float:right;
}
```

If you want them more to the left, then adjust the margin-left property. http://jsfiddle.net/8wRT3/6/

Answer (score 4):

Use a styled unordered list as a container to manage spacing.

```
ul, li { margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none } //add margins to adjust spacing
li { clear:both }
```

Use labels with `float:left` + `display:block` + `width`: or `display:inline-block` + `width:`.

```
<ul>
   <li><label>...</label> <input.... /></li>
   ...
</ul>
```

See: http://alistapart.com/article/prettyaccessibleforms